# Unable to append new values to a List<String> using shared preferences. The new values are going to be of type String

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

**ISSUE:**

Unable to append new values to a `List<String>` using shared preferences. The new values are going to be of type `String`.

**Here's my definition & method :**

```
List<dynamic> deliveryAddressConfirmed = new List(5);
SharedPreferences prefs;
:
: //does something here...& on a specific condition call for gotNewNiceAddress(xxxx);
:
gotNewNiceAddress(dynamic capturedNewAddress) async {
    print(capturedNewAddress);    
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString("deliveryAddressConfirmed", capturedNewAddress);
      var x = deliveryAddressConfirmed.length;
      print("New length = $x");
    setState(() {
      deliveryAddressConfirmed =
          prefs.getStringList('deliveryAddressConfirmed');
    });

  }
```

**Output from console:**

```
D/ViewRootImpl(17086): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
I/flutter (17086): Mountain valley, north 16th street, JC -20293
I/flutter (17086): 
I/flutter (17086):
I/flutter (17086): New length = 0
```

Not sure if i did something wrong in the above code. Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

You save a single string using `prefs.setString` but read expecting a string list when you read with `prefs.getStringList`.

That will not work. You should read what you write. I don't know what you want. A single string? A list of strings? But you can only read exactly what you put in. Your decision.

If you want to add to an existing list, you will have to read the list, append to it and then save it as a list again.

```
// read the old list
final formerSavedList = prefs.getStringList('deliveryAddressConfirmed');

// append the new data to it
formerSavedList.add(newElement);

// and save the new list back to storage
await prefs.setStringList('deliveryAddressConfirmed', formerSavedList);
```

Comment: Like i mentioned in the question, my intention is to add a StringList. Do you know what am i missing in script above to achieve that ?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer: to add to the list, you need to **read it**, then **add to it** and then **save it again**. There is no single method to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but to add something int the list then you
do some thing like below

`deliveryAddressConfirmed.add(prefs.getStringList('deliveryAddressConfirmed'));`

Also, you are printing list before adding something to it, so it will always print 0.
Try calling print statement after setState.